# offline/local browser application with database but without a server behind it

Tags: database, local, google-gears, offlineapps

I want to make a 'application' that operates through a browser.
It should be offline / local on the users machine.
It needs a database to store and retrieve data.
And - because it should be really easy to use - it should run without a server.

The only thing I found so far is the Google Gears API: http://code.google.com/apis/gears/
but I don't really know if it's ideal for my purposes, because the database will contain quite some data and it should be easy to backup.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gears_(software)

Google Gears is discontinued.

I would suggest read about HTML local database/storage options. You might save data locally and sync when there is a connection.

I would be very specific in the interface about whether everything is stored or you are waiting for connection because losing data is a major issue for your users.

Permanent storage on the local machine with a web application is not a generally accepted practice and could generate serious issues.

Comment: sorry for the late 'accept answer', I just developed in a XAMPP Environment and I think the person I developed it for is going to want a website soon anyway ;-)

Comment: interesting new development which could improve storage capabilities by connecting to peers is: http://www.webrtc.org which only needs servers for sharing the data. Might create new opportunities.